# Jquery UI Button Server + Client Click Handlers

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, button, onclick, onclientclick

I am trying to write a simple HTML form using asp.net and Jquery UI but am running into a problem when trying to process click event handlers on a button within this form. I was tryign to use OnClientClick and OnClick but once the clientside method gets accessed and returns the boolean the server side method is not called accordingly( not called at all actually)
Linky to code since I could not get the code tags to work properly: http://pastebin.com/LZNMqASt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the return type of the javascript method was not being accepted as a valid boolean. The below solution fixes the OnClientClick event

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLogin" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_OnClick"
                    OnClientClick="if(ValidateLoginForm() != true) return(false);" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, Actually you are displaying "div#loginForm" element in to the dialog and its not taking the form element.

Put form element inside of **"div#loginForm"** container and the problem will be fixed.

Comment: If you're referring to my javascript methods I tested them individually and they seem to display correctly. My problem lies with the events being handled on the same asp button OnCLientClick & OnClick

Comment: @Kukks, I am not referring any js function, i am giving answer of your qustion that *once the clientside method gets accessed and returns the boolean the server side method is not called accordingly( not called at all actually)*, did you tried what i advised in my answer?

Comment: Um, the form element IS inside of loginForm. My problem is with the event handlers not with DOM manipulation.